# Data Extraction from PDF

Tags: database, ms-access, pdf, import, export

I get 15+ PDF's a day that I have to enter into a database. They are generated from a table where the "Blanks" are filled in from specific table fields. Any tools or python code examples I could use to try and develop a means of extracting the data from the PDF to either write to or create a table to import to the database table? The Database is currently Access mdb.
Thanks

Comment: Please note that [questions asking for the recommendation of off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/2747593). Instead, if you have a specific question about code that *you have written*, please show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and be sure to include a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches that will work.
One simple approach is to simply print the PDF file out to a text file and then have Access import that text. All recent versions of windows allow you to install a “text” printer that outputs the printing of a document to a text file. You can have access “process” a folder of pdfs, print them to text and then import those text files. You might need some VBA to remove “pages” and some extra lines before you import the data into Access.

Another approach is to use Word (Automate from Access) to open a PDF. When word opens a pdf, it converts it to a word document. This approach will even format rows as a word table. You can then pluck out that table data and send that data to word. You can likely pull that text out without writing the data out to a text file – or just use Words “save-as” to a text file (you can automate this process from Access).

Another approach is to use the free Ghost Script library that can extract text from a PDF (this I would consider if did not have word at your disposal).

So which solution is best will much depend on the current software you going to have installed on the computer running Access. Opening the pdf files with word would be my first choice and test.

Comment: This worked for me, I didn't get to implement the whole solution but I have a format that I can search through and pull data out of. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

At my old job we used Cogniview which converted PDF to Excel spreadsheets quite quickly. If you want to use Python, a quick search yielded me this which seems straight forward enough, [PDF to XLS with Python](https://pdftables.com/blog/pdf-to-excel-with-python)

Comment: I seen the web tool for converting but not the API for python, however after testing it there are 2 issues; it is free with restrictions and it is a web tool. The API just lets python connect to the server. I don't want these pdf's being in the open so that tool is unfortunately out of the question. However your response did lead me to PDFQuery and PDF Miner which I am playing around with in python27. Know of any resources for either of these 2 modules?

Comment: I've personally never used either of those. I'm sure there is some excellent documentation out there besides [this](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pdfminer-docs/latest/pdfminer-docs.pdf) and [this](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/manipulating-pdfs-with-python/167). Best of luck!